# Can't access a jBPM .BPMN file from a JBoss servlet

Tags: servlets, jboss, drools, jbpm

I am trying to add jBPM 5.4 support to a servlet.  I have ported a Tomcat servlet to run with JBoss 7.1 and am now trying to add jBPM support to it.  I have run the jbpm-5.4.0.Final-installer-full.zip to get JBoss/jBPM installed with Kepler (I had to patch the installer to install Kepler).  I then copied the following two lines of code from the installer's "evaluation" sample and placed them in my servlet:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Evaluation.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2);
```

After adding the necessary imports I got a clean build.  I the placed the JARS from drools-distribution-5.5.0.Final.zip (from http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads) in my .\WEB-INF\lib and I am able to execute the 1st line of jBPM code (the KnowledgeBuilder line.  However, when I step across the 2nd line (with ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource()) I get the following:

12:29:02,243 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.compiler.BPMN2ProcessProvider'
12:29:02,243 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl.get(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:166)
12:29:02,243 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.drools.compiler.BPMN2ProcessFactory.loadProvider(BPMN2ProcessFactory.java:28)
...

12:29:02,259 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jbpm.bpmn2.BPMN2ProcessProviderImpl from [Module "deployment.MyServer.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
12:29:02,259 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

My questions are:
1) Is this error because of a missing JAR?  If so, can you tell me what JAR is missng?
2) Is placing the sample BPMN file (Evaluation.bpmn) in my classpath sufficient for the code to locate it?

Thank you.
Al

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues. This error is because of missing jar file. I solved this error by adding jbpm-bpmn2-5.4.0.Final.jar to web-inf/lib folder. This jar file is present in jbpm-installer/runtime folder.